# Bayes Theorem Basic Problem.

Tags: conditional-probability

Subject in an experiment are told that either a red or a green light will flash. Each subject is
to guess which light will flash. The subject is told that the probability of a red light is 0.7, independent of
guesses. Assume that the subject is a probability matcher- that is , guesses red with probability .70 and green
with probability .30.
(i) What is the probability that the subject guesses correctly?
(ii) Given that a subject guesses correctly, what is the probability that the light flashed red?

Comment: So you know that it's a Bayes theorem problem. Have you tried solving it with it?

Comment: I guess that .. some mess will come out from the meaning given to "guesses x with **probability** y"

Comment: So the guessed color and the color of the light are independently distributet?